# Looking for a good way to organize big kivy project

Tags: python, oop, kivy

I'm newbe in kivy, I wonder how to use some part of application in separated directory. I want to easly reuse code and have good organization in the project. I don't like put all things into one module like in many tutorials shown, so maybe is there any way to put widget into modules. 
For example:

```
-main:
    -modules/
       -login/
          -main.py
          -main.kv
       -other/
          -ohter.kv
          -other.kv
    -main.py #<- here I want to put widgets from 'login' and 'other'
    -main.kv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually put each widget completely into one file:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<LoginMain>:
    Label:
        text: 'hi'
    Button:
        text: 'press me'
''')

class LoginMain(BoxLayout):
    ...
```

Then you just need to tell Kivy where to find each widget using the [`Factory`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.factory.html). This is easiest to do in your App's build method:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Factory.register('LoginMain', module='myapp.modules.login.main')
        Factory.register('Other', module='myapp.modules.other.other')
        return Factory.LoginMain()
```

Comment: I think it's neater to access widgets via normal python imports, since this works (in practice) exactly the same but doesn't use a new set of tools.

Comment: I like the way with Factory registration but I think the right answer is Builder because i can create or import kv from any location, so my structure can be organized in right way

Comment: @inclement I demonstrated `Factory.register()` use instead since that explicitly makes the widget available in kv, rather than being a side-effect of importing a module.